# Showing country names on hover in Google Map Heat Chart

Tags: html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My boss has asked me to create heat maps using "status" as a percentage.

Creating it was easy:

```
<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=map:fixed=-40,-40,80,80 &chs=348x580&chd=t:60,60,20,60,40,40,60,60,60,40,40,40,20,60,60,20,60,60,40,40,80,40,40,60,40,40,40,80&chco=CCCCCC,FF0000,FFA500,00FF00&chld=AT|BE|CY|CZ|DK|EG|FI|FR|DE|GR|HU|IE|IL|IT|LU|MT|NL|NO|PL|PT|RU|ZA|ES|SE|CH|TR|AE|GB&chf=bg,s,EAF7FE"/>
```

However, they have asked me if it is possible to do the following:

1. Show the country/data when hovering over with a mouse (eg "AT: 60%", or "Austria: 60%").
2. If a country on the list is clicked, to go to a specified page (either AT.html, or preferable Country_Austria.HTML)

I've looked through stackoverflow, and other sites - and I can't find a direct answer to this.

The second option is a "Nice if possible" option for my boss - there is a drop down menu of all the countries, so it isn't necessary. However, he really does want a hover-and-show-details facility on the map if possible.

Any ideas would be most welcome.

Regards,
Steve

Comment: Try https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Comment: Thanks Thomas - that looks spot on, and I see on the documentation that you can react to events...